# Как определить на какой элемент внутри родительского нажали? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть элемент `sidemenu`. В нем есть несколько пунктов. Как определить на какой из них кликнули? Пробовал так:

```
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const { nodeName, textContent } = e.target;
        setnewScroll(parseInt(nodeName.id, 0, 0))
        console.log(`clicked at ${nodeName.id}`)
    }
return (
<div key={"side-menu"} className="side-menu" onClick={handleClick}>
{
SideMenuItems.map((dataItem) => { return (<SideMenuItem key={"sideMenu".concat(dataItem.id)} title={dataItem.title} text_id={dataItem.text_id} className="side__menu-item"></SideMenuItem>) 
})
                    }
</div>
)
```

Но при клике на SideMenuItem не выводится console.log. Как правильно сделать так, чтобы при клике на item запускался handleClick?

Вот SideMenuItem, если нужно:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'


import "./sidemenuItemLink.scss"



export default function SideMenuItem({ text_id, id, title }) {



    return (


        <Link key={id} activeClass='side__menu-item--active' spy={true} hashSpy={true} smooth={true} to={text_id} className="side__menu-item">
            <div className='menu__item-box'><p className='menu__item-text'>{title}</p></div>
        </Link>

    )
}
```

Comment: мне кажется у Вас там опечатка `return ( 
div key={"s` — тут тег не открыт, по идее должны были быть ошибки

Comment: @PavelMayorov Убрал.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Да, не скопировал открывание тега. Поправил.

Comment: Что вам мешает в `SideMenuItem` прокинуть `handleClick`, чтобы в него `id` элемента передавался?  `(event)=>handleClick(id)`

Comment: @xydope handleClick хотелось бы оставить в родительском элементе, так как там определен State, который надо менять при клике на элемент меню.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Проброс обработчика вам никак не помешает изменять стейт родителя, см. пример ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом код был рабочий, но некоторые действия на мой взгляд не правильные. Я добавил передачу `id` и присвоил его параграфу в `SideMenuItem`. Так же я не знаю зачем Вам `nodeName` (это строка у нее нет `id`) — `e.target.id` вполне достаточно. Атрибут `key` используется только для компонент порадждаемых внутри метода `map` отдельно его использовать нет никакого смысла.

```js
function SideMenuItem({ text_id, id, title }) {
  return (
    <a className="side__menu-item">
      <div className='menu__item-box'>
        <p id={id} className='menu__item-text'>{title}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const SideMenuItems = [
    {  
      id: 1,
      title:"Item1",
      text_id:"1" 
    },
    {  
      id: 2,
      title:"Item2",
      text_id:"2" 
    }
  ]

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const { nodeName, textContent } = e.target;
    console.log(`clicked at ${e.target.id}`, nodeName, textContent)
  }
  return (
    <div key={"side-menu"} className="side-menu" onClick={handleClick}>
    {
      SideMenuItems.map((dataItem) => 
        (<SideMenuItem 
          key={"sideMenu".concat(dataItem.id)} 
          title={dataItem.title} 
          text_id={dataItem.text_id} 
          id={dataItem.id} 
          className="side__menu-item">
        </SideMenuItem>) 
      )
    }
    </div>
  )
}    

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Для решения с `Link` лучше использовать программный скролинг вот песочница с [примером](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-example-qc5tlr) где в принципе `Link` не нужен, а вместо него используется `scroller`.

Comment: К сожалению, на Link из reactScroll такой способ не работает. В консоли нет log-а clicked at

Comment: Линк на сколько я знаю сразу редиректит, вам нужно редиректится вручную из handleClick

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Вот [тут](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll/blob/master/examples/basic/app.js) есть пример из официального источника как это делается, если не разберетесь создайте песочницу в сodesandbox я продемонстрирую

Comment: @Konstantin_SH я сам создал песочницу [ознакомьтесь](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-example-qc5tlr)

Comment: У меня почему-то не выводит id элемента. Оно пустое. console.log ({`${e.target}) работает, а вот console.log(`${e.target.id}`) уже выводит пустую строку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515793/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-e-target-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-react Вот, создал вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, если не трудно.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH вот [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-example2-m5l4hb?file=/src/index.js:0-1726)  по Вашему новому вопросу, вообще лучше тот вопрос удалить (не хорошо дублировать вопросы) в данном случае я сделал через дата аттрибут, пройдитесь внимательно по коду убедитесь что все в нем понятно, Как я уже писал ранее `key` это чисто реактовский аттрибут для `map` больше он нигде никогда не используется. Для валидности страницы `id` должны быть уникальны, в Вашем случае хватит `id` на параграфе

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался с этим. Тоже сделал через data-атрибут. Использовал getAtribute метод.