# Почему e.target выводит в консоль, а его атрибуты - пустые? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть элемент меню и в нем несколько дочерних элементов. Задавал связанный вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1515662/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-react?noredirect=1#comment2721134_1515662). Сейчас код элемента такой:

```
import React from 'react'

import "./sidemenuItemLink.scss"



export default function SideMenuItem({ text_id, id, title }) {

        <div key={id} id = {id} className="side__menu-item" data_to={text_id}>
            <div className='menu__item-box'><p id={id} className='menu__item-text'>{title}</p></div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Определить по какому элементу кликнули пытаюсь так:

```
    const scrollTo = (el, offset = 0) => {
        scroller.scrollTo(el, {
            duration: 800,
            delay: 0,
            smooth: "easeInOutQuart",
            offset: offset
        })
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        const target = e.target
        console.log(`clicked at ${target.data_to}`);
        scrollTo(`text${target.data_to}`);
        console.log(e.target)
    }
...

return (
<div key={"side-menu"} className="side-menu" onClick={handleClick}>

                    {
                        SideMenuItems.map((dataItem) => { return (<SideMenuItem key={"sideMenu".concat(dataItem.id)} title={dataItem.title} text_id={dataItem.text_id} className="side__menu-item"></SideMenuItem>) })
                    }

                </div>
)
```

Структура SideMenuItems такая:

```
const SideMenuItems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "title1",
        text_id: "unic_text_scroll_to_1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "title2",
        text_id: "unic_text_scroll_to_2"
    },
...
]
```

Теперь клик по дочернему элемену вызывает handleClick, но в консоли я вижу пустое место, когда пытаюсь вывести id или data_to пунктам меню, при этом сам e.target выводится "на ура":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем причина?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Если нужно значение любого атрибута, то используйте target.getAttribute('data_to'), если data-атрибут - надо через дефис писать data-to, допустим. А обращаться через target.dataset.to

Comment: @PavelNazarian, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy подумал, что не тянет на полноценный ответ

Comment: @PavelNazarian, вполне тянет, если добавишь пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К любым атрибутам можно универсально обратиться через метод getAttribute(). То есть к `data_to` можно обратиться так - `element.getAttribute('data_to')`.
У data-атрибутов синтаксис через дефис. То есть вместо `data_to` необходимо написать `data-to`. Тогда к ним можно обратиться в том числе через свойство объекта `dataset`. Таким образом - `element.dataset.to`.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const t = e.target;
  if (t.classList.contains('side__menu-item')) {
    console.log(t.id);
    console.log(t.getAttribute('key'));
    console.log(t.getAttribute('data_to')); 
    console.log(t.dataset.to);
  }
})
```

```css
.side__menu-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div key='324234' id = '1' class="side__menu-item" data-to='text_1' data_to='text_1'>       
</div>
<div key='123454' id = '2' class="side__menu-item" data-to='text_2' data_to='text_2'>       
</div>
<div key='656543' id = '3' class="side__menu-item" data-to='text_3' data_to='text_3'>       
</div>
```